# Maintaining state during interactive command line prompt

Tags: haskell, recursion, io, state, monads

I want to write a toy program that has an interactive prompt and that can save and display all previous inputs. This is my first attempt, but does not compile (using ghc):

```
import System.IO
import Control.Monad.State

data ProgramState = ProgramState
    { events :: [Int] }     -- Placeholder for now

parse_input :: String -> State ProgramState Bool
parse_input prompt = do
    putStr prompt
    hFlush stdout
    current_state <- get
    str <- getLine
    case str of
        "c" -> do 
            put (current_state { events = [1,2,3] } )   -- this should become actual appending
            return True
        "l" -> return True    
        "q" -> return False  
        "quit" -> return False
        "h" -> return True
        _ -> do 
            putStrLn "Invalid input."
            parse_input prompt

main :: IO ()
main = do
    should_continue <- parse_input "Enter your command."
    if should_continue then main else return ()
```

```
main.hs:9:5: error:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    • Couldn't match type ‘IO’                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                     with ‘StateT ProgramState Data.Functor.Identity.Identity’                                                                                                                                                                                                 
      Expected type: StateT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                       ProgramState Data.Functor.Identity.Identity ()                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      Actual type: IO ()
```

Note: line 9 is `putStr prompt`
The same error is given for lines 10, 12, 22, 27.

I have since thought of doing the recursion purely inside parse_input, in which case I don't seem to need the state monad. But I am still curious why I get the compilation error. Any help is appreciated, I am very new to Haskell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be mixing values of type `State s a` with values of type `IO a`. In your `main` action, you call `parse_input` in a context expecting `IO`. In `parse_input`, you call `putStr` and so on in a context expecting `State`. That's not going to work!

The usual way to do this kind of thing is to switch from `State` to `StateT`, and import `Control.Monad.IO.Class`. Now, you can use

```
evalStateT :: StateT s m a -> s -> m a
```

to "lower" your loop to `IO`, and

```
-- liftIO :: IO a -> StateT s IO a
liftIO :: MonadIO m => IO a -> m a
```

to "lift" the `IO` actions to `StateT` within the loop. Now (untested code ahead):

```hs
-- Needed for flexible use of
-- the MonadState class.
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import System.IO
-- You almost always want the "strict"
-- version of `StateT`; the lazy one is weird.
import Control.Monad.State.Strict
import Control.Monad.IO.Class

data ProgramState = ProgramState
    { events :: [Int] }     -- Placeholder for now

-- Renaming your function to follow convention.
parseInput
  :: (MonadState ProgramState m, MonadIO m)
  => String -> m Bool
parseInput prompt = do
    str <- liftIO $ do
      putStr prompt
      hFlush stdout
      getLine
    current_state <- get
    case str of
        "c" -> do 
            put (current_state { events = [1,2,3] } )   -- this should become actual appending
            return True
        "l" -> return True    
        "q" -> return False  
        "quit" -> return False
        "h" -> return True
        _ -> do 
            liftIO $ putStrLn "Invalid input."
            parseInput prompt

main :: IO ()
main = do
    -- You need to supply the initial state; I've just guessed here.
    should_continue <- evalStateT (parseInput "Enter your command.") (ProgramState [])
    if should_continue then main else return ()
```

As Daniel Wagner points out, this will not preserve the state from one `main` run to the next. If that's your intention, you can write

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = evalStateT loop (ProgramState [])
  where
    loop = do
      should_continue <- parseInput "Enter your command."
      if should_continue then loop else return ()
```

If you like, you can import `Control.Monad` and shorten this to

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = evalStateT loop (ProgramState [])
  where
    loop = do
      should_continue <- parseInput "Enter your command."
      when should_continue loop
```

Final note: if you want to capture the final state of your loop, use `runStateT` instead of `evalStateT`.

Comment: I don't think this will preserve the state during the `main` recursion, which sort of seems to be the point of the exercise.

Comment: @DanielWagner, it will not. I didn't feel like I had enough of a sense of the point of the exercise to guess...

Comment: Okay, I gave an alternative.